# Using DEROctetString vs pure Extension

Tags: java, certificate, bouncycastle, x509certificate

I am using bouncy castle librarires to  add extensions to my X509V3Certificate certificate.Let's say that I want to add  *ExtendedKeyUsage* extension to my certificate.I am using X509V3CertificateBuilder class  and addExtension() method so I do this.

```
   X509V3CertificateBuilder cf=...;
   ExtendedKeyUsage eku = new ExtendedKeyUsage(KeyPurposeId.anyExtendedKeyUsage);
cf.addExtension(Extension.ExtendedKeyUsage, false , eku);
```

But what I am seeing in some examples all over the web , people are doing next thing

```
cf.addExtension(Extension.ExtendedKeyUsage, false, new DEROctetString(eku));
```

I don't get any warnings from compiler when I use first method(without DEROctetString) but I don't know what is the difference, which way is better, and are they both correct?

Comment: Use an ASN.1 parser and print out the differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: your (first) method is correct

For background, the actual `extensions` field in (the body=`TBSCertificate` of) an X.509 certificate represents/encodes the value of each extension [as an OCTET STRING 'wrapping' the DER encoding of the actual value](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1).

But in Bouncy when calling the older overloads of `X509v3CertificateBuilder.addExtension` whose third paramater is either `ASN1Encodable` (the value object) or `byte[]` (its encoding) you don't need to do the OCTET STRING yourself; the `ExtensionsGenerator` used internally by the builder does it for you. In fact, creating `DEROctetString` yourself here actually creates (a cert containing) an extension whose value is 'double wrapped' -- an OCTET STRING containing the DER of another OCTET STRING containing the DER of the actual value, which is wrong.

However, recent versions (1.53 up) contain another overload which instead of separate OID, boolean, value takes a single `org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Extension` object which contains those three -- and creating that object is different: its constructors take either the encoding (and wrap it) or a `DEROctetString` object you create yourself, and whose constructors in turn take either the encoding or the encodable. (It's actually declared as the superclass `ASN1OctetString` but you want to use the `DER` subclass because cert bodies need to be entirely DER.) Thus (any of) the following are also correct:

```
certbuilder.addExtension(new Extension(Extension.extendedKeyUsage, false, eku.getEncoded()))
certbuilder.addExtension(new Extension(Extension.extendedKeyUsage, false, new DEROctetString(eku)))
certbuilder.addExtension(new Extension(Extension.extendedKeyUsage, false, new DEROctetString(eku.getEncoded())))
```

Are you sure it is not one of the latter two that you saw elsewhere?