# The method SubjectKeyIdentifier(SubjectPublicKeyInfo) is undefined for the type X509Generator

Tags: java

I took a code open source and I try to use it in my project but I have this error : The method SubjectKeyIdentifier(SubjectPublicKeyInfo) is undefined for the type X509Generator.
My code is the following :

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1EncodableVector;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERSequence;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.AuthorityKeyIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.BasicConstraints;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.ExtendedKeyUsage;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Extensions;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.GeneralName;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.GeneralNames;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.KeyPurposeId;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.KeyUsage;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectKeyIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Extensions;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Name;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.X509Principal;
import org.bouncycastle.x509.X509V3CertificateGenerator;

...

private SubjectKeyIdentifier getSubjectKeyIdentifier(PublicKey publicKey)
    throws IOException
  {
    InputStream         input;
    SubjectPublicKeyInfo    keyInfo;

    input = new ByteArrayInputStream(publicKey.getEncoded());
    keyInfo = new SubjectPublicKeyInfo((ASN1Sequence)new ASN1InputStream(input).readObject());

    return SubjectKeyIdentifier(keyInfo);
  }
```

I think I need to use 509Extension but I don't know how. And i don't know if it's a good way to solve my problem too.
Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You redacted away the name of your class but I bet it's `X509Generator`. Although `SubjectKeyIdentifier` is the name of a bouncycastle class that is imported and thus visible, `return SubjectKeyIdentifier (args)` is not a valid syntax for a class name so the compiler instead tries to interpret it as a *method* name in *your* class, which does not exist, hence the error.

Possibly you wanted to call a constructor of this class, or a static method in it. But neither of those exists to take a `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` as an argument, probably because computation of the keyid from the key is nontrivial; see [rfc 3280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3280#section-4.2.1.2) or [5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.2). Instead (assuming you have bcpkix as well as bcprov) use [JcaX509ExtensionUtils.createSubjectKeyIdentifier](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/cert/jcajce/JcaX509ExtensionUtils.html#createSubjectKeyIdentifier-java.security.PublicKey-) (or its Truncated sibling) either directly on the (JCE) PublicKey object, or using the superclass `X509ExtensionUtils` on a `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` which you can construct directly from the encoding (without handling the ASN1 explicitly) using

```
SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(encoding /*e.g. publickey.getEncoded()*/)
```

With `X509V3CertificateGenerator` (which in case you haven't noticed is deprecated, obsoleted by `X509v3CertificateBuilder` in bcpkix) you don't need to manage the `X509Extension` objects yourself, although they exist internally. You just call

```
generator.addExtension(oid_obj_or_string,boolean critical,encodable_or_bytearray)
```

Related for the newer version: [Using DEROctetString vs pure Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50535113/using-deroctetstring-vs-pure-extension)

> And i don't know if it's a good way to solve my problem too.

Since you gave us no clue what your problem is, neither do I.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your answer !
I just solved my problem thanks your explain ! How have you the idea to use JcaX509ExtensionUtils ?
Thanks again for your help !